# Modify each element of a Python list and combine results into a string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say there is a list of objects of type "dog", and each dog has a parameter "name". For example:

```
dogs = [dog1, dog2, dog3]
```

is a list consisting of three dogs with names Rocky, Spot, and Daisy.

I am trying to access "name" of each dog and generate a string like "Rocky, Spot, Daisy". I understand that I need to use List Comprehensions, but the specifics turned out to be trickier than I thought.

I tried using

```
result = (dog.name+", " for dog in dogs)
```

but *result* becomes a generator rather than a string.

I also tried

```
result = ",".join(layers.name)
```

but I didn't find a way to access the "name" field of each dog.

I know how to solve the problem using brute force, but I would really want to implement an elegant, "python" solution instead.
Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: You're almost there -- just combine your two solutions: result = ','.join(dog.name for dog in dogs)

Comment: have you tried `result = ", ".join( [dog.name for dog in dogs] )` ?

Comment: @KacperReutt - that looks like an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 8):

You have to combine the generator with `join`:

```
result = ', '.join(dog.name for dog in dogs)
```

Comment: this strikes me as the most Pythonic possible answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You can plug the generator into join.

```
>>> ", ".join(dog.name for dog in dogs)
'Rocky, Spot, Daisy'
```

Comment: No need for the extra `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
result = (dog.name+", " for dog in dogs)
```

is a generator comprehension/expression not a list comprehension. You can use that like so:

```
>>> dogs = ['Rocky', 'Spot', 'Daisy']
>>> result = (dog for dog in dogs)
>>> for dog in result:
...     print(dog)
...
Rocky
Spot
Daisy
```

Or for your specific case:

```
>>> result = (dog for dog in dogs)
>>> ', '.join(result)
'Rocky, Spot, Daisy'
```

Comment: But `dogs` is a list of `dog` objects, with a `name` parameter. Not a list of names.

Comment: IT will work the same with a class, I didn't recreate his class in my interpreter but the concept is the same. He has already created the generator object now he just needs to consume it

Answer (score 1):

If you combine list comprehension with `", ".join` you get:

`result = ", ".join( [dog.name for dog in dogs] )`

Comment: There's no need for the list comprehension; a generator expression works just as well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right, you can as well use `result = ", ".join( (dog.name for dog in dogs) )`. In this case it really doesn't make any difference.